# How to use hideshow to fold the `#ifdef`

Tags: c, hideshow

I use the package `hideshow` to fold/unfold codes. Recently I write some code to enable folding the `#ifdef, #endif` in `c-mode` like that

```lisp
  (add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
               '(c-mode "#ifdef"
                         "#endif"
                         "/[*/]"
                         nil
                         nil))
```

I don't know why it doesn't work (just nothing happend when I used it).

I know another package `hide-ifdef`, but I hope to use `hideshow` to implement this function to make my operation more integrated.